# Who shot down Jack Mason's transporter in the beginning?

Tags: video-games, pariah

In the prologue to *[Pariah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pariah_%28video_game%29)*, the ship that transports Karina is shot down by an unknown party. It happens over Scavenger territory, but it apparently Scavengers wouldn't be properly equipped to shoot down a ship. Jack works for the Alliance, so they are out of the picture, although they become the enemy for large parts of the story. Also, we learn that

> Jack is actually a double agent and secretly works for the Shroud

so they are out of the picture, as well.

So, who did it? What twisted plot element would explain it was shot down in the first place?

Comment: Oh, that is a blast from the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, this is clearly explained in the link you provided:
SPOILERS!

> It is eventually revealed that Colonel Stockton masterminded the attack on Mason's transport, and that he has paid off the Scavengers to capture Karina for him. However, he double-crossed the Scavengers, captured Karina himself, and now refuses to pay them.

So, technically you could argue that

> it was the Alliance that shot down Mason's transport but it was specifically Stockton who did it to get Karina back so he could use the virus she carries to kill the Shroud.

Comment: Nice. Must have missed that. The story isn't very well told, if you ask me. At least, I was left with some serious head scratching (IIRC).